# How to make prettier format style tags inside shadowDom.innerHTML in web components?

Tags: javascript, web-component, prettier

It seems running prettier ignores embedded style tags (and code) inside backticks:

```
import Base from './Base.js';

class NavBar extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    static get name() {
        return `${this.ns}-navbar`;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <style>
      .navbar {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-start;
      }
      
      .navbar a {
        margin: 0 .4rem;
        text-decoration: none;
      }    

        .navbar a.active {
            font-weight: 700;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="/recent.html" class="${this.isCurrentPage('/recent') ? 'active' : ''}">recent</a>
        <a href="/popular.html" class="${
                    this.isCurrentPage('/popular') ? 'active' : ''
                }">popular</a>
        <a href="/tags.html" class="${this.isCurrentPage('/tags') ? 'active' : ''}">tags</a>
        <a href="/" class="${this.isCurrentPage('/$') ? 'active' : ''}">home</a>
    </nav>
`;
    }
}

customElements.define(NavBar.name, NavBar);
```

.prettierrc:

```
{
    "useTabs": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "printWidth": 100,
    "arrowParens": "avoid"
}
```

Command: `npx prettier  -w .`

Is there anyway to get prettier to format the code inside backticks?

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately, it is not possible for prettier do that.

Comment: Execute attachShadow in the constructer, because the connectedCallback can run multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Until [HTML modules](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4854408103854080) and [CSS module scripts](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5948572598009856) land in the browser, you'll need a bundler that supports importing text files into strings. webpack does this using rawloader (if I'm not mistaken this is available without an explicit loader in webpack 5), in Vite.js it works out of the box.

This way you can separate your JS, HTML and CSS again.